# Backing up Mysql – indexes and restoring them on a different computer

Tags: mysql

I have spent most of the day optimizing a Mysql 5.0.x database – now I need to get the changes on to the production server

How do I make a backup of table’s index settings and then restore them on the production database server?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a mysqldump --no-data on both databases and diff them by hand. Alternatively, you could use something like [SQL Fairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/), which can diff two databases and output the SQL required to change one database's schema to match the other. I believe it can either work directly with the databases, or with the SQL generated with mysqldump --no-data.